# Guardian Angels and Hinduism

Tags: other-religions

Judeo christian religious traditions has got a concept that , each person on earth has got a guardian angel to take care of his/her need. They keep monitoring each person ,  help their spiritual progress and try to communicate with him/her with different signs. If person is spiritually more evolved he can communicate with them.

I understand that hinduism has got 33 crore devas , upadevas, gandharvas , kinnaras and other divine beings. But I could not find any reference to the concept of having an angel assigned to each person.

What is the take of hinduism on guardian angel?

Comment: I suppose closest equivalent may be Pitris or spirits of departed ancestors.

Comment: I dont think pitris continuously monitor their descendants .Only thing I have heard is , they come once in a year during shraddha ceremony.I also not sure there would be a pitri for each person.

Comment: I think God always take care of us

Comment: Ishta Devata when is propiciated

Comment: Still , that does not equal to guardian angel. Ishta devata are usually for families or large set of descendents. Not on individual basis

Comment: See here we have coorelation between what you see in the universe and the body.. We have whatever in the universe inside our body, Are you in control of you breath first? no right than who is controlling now (we call mukhyaprana devaru (hanuman)) Are you in control of the five sense? no right ( we call it indra whos is sitting inside you and make see,taste, smell, talk, walk and feel) like this all the 33 crore gods are there already inside your body working for you, but only when you realize than you can see this thing that you are not doing anything somebody is doing for you..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood Hinduism, there is no concept of guardian angel to take care of his/her need.  One has to strive to develop physically as well as spiritually.

Sri Krishna says the same in B.G. as follows;

> उद्धरेदात्मनाऽऽत्मानं नात्मानमवसादयेत्।
>
> आत्मैव ह्यात्मनो बन्धुरात्मैव रिपुरात्मनः।।6.5।।
>
> By the self (Atman), i.e., by the mind, which is unattached to sense-objects, one should raise the self. One should not allow the self to sink by a mind which is of the contrary kind. **'For the self alone,' i.e., the mind alone is the friend of the self; and it alone is the foe of the self**.

Answer (score 0):

There is however concept of paramatma in sanatana dharma as in srimad bhagvatam 7.7.32

```
   हरि: सर्वेषु भूतेषु भगवानास्त ईश्वर: । इति भूतानि मनसा कामैस्तै:
    साधु मानयेत् ॥ ३२ ॥ But although You reside within the heart, You
    are very far away from those whose minds are disturbed by their
    entanglement in material work. Indeed, no one can grasp You by his
    material powers, for You reveal Yourself only in the hearts of those
    who have learned to appreciate Your transcendental qualities.
```

there is also another verse from Srimad Bhagvatam 7.6.20-23

```
The Supreme Personality of Godhead, the supreme controller, who is
infallible and indefatigable, is present in different forms of life,
from the inert living beings [sthāvara], such as the plants, to
Brahmā, the foremost created living being. He is also present in the
varieties of material creations and in the material elements, the
total material energy and the modes of material nature [sattva-guṇa,
rajo-guṇa and tamo-guṇa], as well as the unmanifested material
nature and the false ego. Although He is one, He is present
everywhere, and He is also the transcendental Supersoul, the cause
of all causes, who is present as the observer in the cores of the
hearts of all living entities. He is indicated as that which is
pervaded and as the all-pervading Supersoul, but actually He cannot
be indicated. He is changeless and undivided. He is simply perceived
as the supreme sac-cid-ānanda [eternity, knowledge and bliss]. Being
covered by the curtain of the external energy, to the atheist He
appears nonexistent.
```

Vedic tradition goes far beyond humans to planta animals and even atoms.