# What do Hindu scriptures say about Doppelgängers?

Tags: omens, ghosts

A "doppelgänger" is an entity that takes the form of a living person. In western traditions, it has been often seen as a malicious entity with harmful intentions and said to signify doom.

My question is, are there any similar beings equivalent to Doppelgängers in Hinduism? If yes, what do they signify? And how should one deal with such entities?

Comment: Doppelganger is not a Sanskrit word.  Asuras and other divine beings can take form a living persons. This will give opinionated answers or it can be even considered as off-topic.

Comment: [Is comparison of a topic with other religions on-topic?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/198/5212). This question is asking Hindu equivalent of a tradition. There have been many questions like this. I can't see how it is an off-topic question. [Guardian Angels and Hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8126/5212), [What is Hinduism's stand on “circumcision”?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26483/5212) are some examples. This is a Hinduism site and not a Sanskrit site. We can ask about terms from any language. Everyone knows doppelganger is not Sanskrit term.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have read something about entities that can take on the form they wish... but they may or may not qualify as dopplegangers with malicious intent. Just don't remember where I I read it. Will try to see if I can find that source.

Comment: From a Hindu perspective (opinion), a Doppelgänger is really a projection of a person's own astral body giving him an omen of his impending death. According to several Hindu scriptures, Swamis, and Gurus, and according to the Aghori Vimalananda in "Aghora" series by Robert Svoboda, before we are about to die or get sick, it is first shown in the astral body and then it is manifested to the physical. This process can take months to years. A true Yogi or spiritually advanced person would be able to know the exact time of their death or illness by observing their astral body and breath (prana).